# LMDE - Blank terminal on boot, no input

Tags: debian, grub2, lmde, plymouth

I was having an issue where my machine was continuously accessing the hard drive but was stuck and totally unusable for an hour. After forcing it down, it starts up and shows the GRUB menu and the LM logo. After a couple minutes, the screen goes to black, showing only a flashing cursor in the NW corner of the screen. At this point it takes no input and I cannot switch to another terminal. The only matter of recourse left is to tap the power button, at which point the logo returns and it proceeds to shut down.

When I started it in rescue mode and checked out the logs, the one thing that stood out was that it was performing `fsck` on `/dev/sda7` (where the main LMDE partition is located) but exiting with an error code of 8.

I started again and pressed esc at the logo to track the messages. The very last message on the screen:

```
Starting Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit
```

It seems this is a common problem when graphics drivers are updated, but the thing is I never updated them. This isn't a gaming machine by any stretch:

```
Graphics:  Card: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID 00:02.0 
X.Org 1.14.3 drivers intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution 1366x768@60.1hz 
GLX Renderer Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile GLX Version 3.0 Mesa 9.2.2 Direct Rendering Yes
```

Where should I look?

**Update**

Whatever the issue is, it's not enough to cripple it. I can get into it as normal by going into recovery mode, authing in as root, exiting, authing as my normal user, and running `startx`, but this is a hack I don't want to use every time I boot up.

Comment: How did you install Debian? If you did like me, and installed it threw a flash drive, just keep the flash drive plugged in and it should work properly...

Comment: I installed it from a burned DVD.

Comment: So... It should work properly. What was the last thing you could do on it? And what was the last thing you did?

Comment: I can still use it, but as in the update, the way to get in is not so kosher. When it went down I was just perusing a page on Firefox.

Comment: Hmm... What OS is it? And be very specific... Some OS's are not ready to be released and are in dire need of updates. And don't just say Debian... Because i know that... Is it Jessy? Wheezy?

Comment: LMDE x64 201403 build with Cinnamon (so probably Wheezy) http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=102

Comment: Check my answer for an update

Comment: @Drissident Rage: I fixed the update... I'm an idiot...